# How to check whether a session exists?

Tags: java, session, nullpointerexception

I want to check whether a session exists or not in a webpage, however on doing so if, session does not exists compiler receives a `NullPointerException`. How to check a session so that it does not produce this Exception?
Consider, session does not exist

```
try
    {
        HttpSession currentsession=request.getSession(false);
        if(currentsession==null) || currentsession.getAttribute("current-emailID").equals(null))
        {
            //Code to redirect to default page
        }
    }
    catch(NullPointerException npe)
    {
            //Code to redirect to default page
    }
```

Comment: Isn't `currentsession.getAttribute("current-emailID")` returning `null`? Try to replace `.equals(null)` with `== null`. It prevents you from a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: You're not supposed to `catch` unchecked exceptions

Comment: @kocko unchecked exceptions are such because you do not _need_ to catch them. Any program that is supposed to be dependable will need to handle unexpected issues, that means catching RuntimeExceptions.

Comment: @SamuelÅslund I can't think of any feasible reason to catch runtime exceptions (besides to catch, log and then rethrow). IMO, there can always be an alternate solution to handle runtime exceptions(like adding null checks to avoid NPE etc) .

Comment: @SaifAsif There are at least two very valid reasons to catch runtime exceptions. 1) The Program should not crash and/or loose data because of someones mistake, especially for a 24/7 app. 2) The case generating the exception is so obscure that polluting the code with guard and "throws" clauses will make the code unnecessarily complex and hard to read. I totally agree about the try/catch above tho.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the issues with your code:

- A `NullPointerException` may be thrown if `request == null` but that's very unlikely.
- In order to check for nulls with the `currentSession.getAttribute`, use `==`. Do **not** invoke the method `equals` as your attribute could be `null`, hence you'd throw a `NPE` by invoking `equals` on a `null` object.
- And as [kocko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1003142/kocko) mentions, catching a `RuntimeException` is bad practice in many cases - specifically `NullPointerException`s. You should remove the `try`/`catch` block in this instance.

Comment: I agree with removing the try/catch in this specific case but saying that "catching RuntimeExceptions is bad practice" is a little too wide generalization. Writing code that depends on catching those instead of checking it's inputs would be bad practice in most cases tho.

Comment: @SamuelÅslund you are right - a bit too radical. Some `RuntimeException`s need to be caught. Fixing.

Answer (score 0):

when `currentsession` is null, then `currentsession.getAttribute("current-emailID")` will throw a `NullPointerException`,

when `currentsession` is not null, then `currentsession.getAttribute("current-emailID")`is null or not null, in either case you test should be using `== null` not `.equals(null)`

so all in all your test should be `(currentsession!=null) && (currentsession.getAttribute("current-emailID")!=null)`

by this way when the currentsession is null, you prevent the second condition from being executed and then the exception being throwed.